# Как установить Thumbnail Категории через код?

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

Господа, не пойму как установить картинку для категории в WP? В теме они поддерживаются, вручную установить можно. set_post_thumbnail - не отрабатывает. У меня есть код:

```
foreach ($house['renderer'] as $foto) {
        $img_id[]['picture'] = media_sideload_image($foto, 'product_cat_' . $insert_res['term_id'], '', 'id');
    }
    update_field('foto', $img_id, 'product_cat_' . $insert_res['term_id']);
    set_post_thumbnail('product_cat_' . $insert_res['term_id'], $img_id[0]['picture']);
```

Загружаю фото со стороннего ресурса, получаю id фото в массив, передаю в update_field - отрабатывает отлично, фотки подключаются в множственное поле ACF с изображениями. $img_id[0]['picture'] - ID вложения, всё верно. Но не работает((

Comment: Наверное потому что `set_post_thumbnail()` устанавливает thumbnail для записи, а не для таксономии, а это разные вещи. В WordPress нет как таковой поддержки табнейлов для категорий и по Вашему коду, я так подозреваю что это WooCommerce, что следовало бы уточнить задавая вопрос. Используйте `update_term_meta($product_cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id);`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Пока нет возможности проверить, к сожалению, но за ответ спасибо!